# how to remove cropped image from original image

Tags: iphone, image-processing, ios5

I am developing an image processing application in ios5. In this application I want to select part of image and then delete that part from the original image.

I tried cropping the image. Cropping is giving me the image that I have selected. But it is not deleting that image from original image.

Any idea how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the piece of code that i have used in one of my application and it works perfectly

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(someImageView.frame.size);
[someImageView.image drawInRect:someImageView.frame];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(somex, somey, somewidth, someheight);
CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
someImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

For this to work with your code, you need to create a imageview if you dont have one and then replace the `someimageview` variable with your imageview.

You need to provide the values for `somex, somey, somewidth and someheight`.